# Spring boot Hibernate Teradata Unable to determine Dialect to use

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, teradata

Application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
```

Data source bean :

```
@Bean  
public DataSource dataSource() {
  return  DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
            .driverClassName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
       .username("dbc")
     .password("dbc")
      .url("jdbc:teradata://name/DBC")

       .build();

    }
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Comment: share application.properties plz?

Comment: this is whole application.properties
,i have added DataSource bean from code in post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing dataSource bean from java config and let spring-boot initilize dataSource by providing more properties in apllication.properties:

```
#DataSource configuration
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:teradata://name/DBC
spring.datasource.username=dbc
spring.datasource.password=dbc

#JPA/HIbernate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
```